# Code Composer Studio: build fails with message "cannot open file"

Tags: build, code-composer, ti-dsp

I have several Code Composer Studio projects which have compiled successfully, but now they all fail at the linking stage with the error message "cannot open file" then the name of the first first .obj file to be linked.

I am certain that the necessary object files are available, in the correct place.

I have googled the problem and found (mostly on TI formums) other users reporting the same issue with CCS back to version 5. No-one, as far as I can determine, has indentified the underlying problem and provided a solution.

I have tried, without success

- Changing permissions of libraries in TI\CCS7 folder tree.
- Changing permissions of ...\AppData\Local\Temp (system %TEMP% target)
- Changing the project to use a different version of the CCS compiler and linker. Tried 16.9, 17.9, 18.1. No difference.
- Running CCS as administrator
- Clean and rebuild the projects affected
- Restart the machine hosting CCS
- Go back to another (previously working) workspace. This workspace now fails to build too
- Install V8 of Code Composer. Problem persists
- Recreate a new version of a project that fails to link

Not tried but suggested

- Disable anti-virus software while building (IT policy will not let me)

Not tried (but they may help if the length of the command line passed to the linker is the problem, causing the system to read ccsObjs.opt)

- Building a very small project
- Restructuring the project into fewer, bigger files.

I have run the TI linker cl2000.exe from the command line in the project Release folder and get the same error response. So the problem is with cl2000, not gmake, not CCS, not Eclipse.

I have successfully built my project on another developer's machine. I cannot determine what is different.

I am running CCS verion 7.2 (now CCS  Version: 8.0.0.00016) on Windows 7, 64 bit, with Windows and CCS fully updated with latest available patches

Can anyone suggest what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was caused by a minor error in one of the TI supplied command files (DSP2833x_Headers_nonBIOS.cmd). The "/" starting the comment on the first line had been deleted by mistake. It seems errors in the .cmd files lead to very hard to solve build errors.